# Wso2 - Change Resident Identity Provider to use different certificate other than wso2carbon

Tags: saml, wso2-identity-server

Could you please let me know how I can change the Resident metadata value to have a different certificate other than ws02 where I have signed a metadata using a specific cert.  Seems IS is signing the SAMLRequest using its own cert so i get an invalid signature when sending a SAML Request to the Identity Provider.

I change the certificate alias on service provider configuration from IS console to the appropriate certificate but doesn't seem to overwrite signing it and still using the standard wso2 certificate.

Is there somewhere in the IS configuration where I can change the wso2carbon cert to one of my own so it will apply to identity provider resident?

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the primary keystore configured by the / element in the /repository/conf/carbon.xml file is used for internal data encryption (encrypting data in internal data stores and configuration files) as well as for signing messages that are communicated with external parties. However, it is sometimes a common requirement to have separate keystores for communicating messages with external parties (such SAML, OIDC id_token signing) and for encrypting information in internal data stores. This is because, for the first scenario of signing messages, the keystore certificates need to be frequently renewed. However, for encrypting information in internal data stores, the keystore certificates should not be changed frequently because the data that is already encrypted will become unusable every time the certificate changes.

This feature will be available from IS 5.5.0 WUM and above. You can follow steps in [1] to configure multiple keystores.

```
<InternalKeyStore>
  <Location>${carbon.home}/repository/resources/security/internal.jks</Location>
  <Type>JKS</Type>
  <Password>wso2carbon</Password>
  <KeyAlias>wso2carbon</KeyAlias>
  <KeyPassword>wso2carbon</KeyPassword>
</InternalKeyStore>
```

[1]https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Configuring+Keystores+in+WSO2+Products#ConfiguringKeystoresinWSO2Products-second_keystore_internal_dataConfiguringaseparatekeystoreforencryptingdataininternaldatastores

Comment: Thanks this issue is now fix